# How to get Lattitude and Longitude by network provider in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location, wifi

I want to get the lat and long by network only(don't want to get by GPS) in objective-c, i have used CoreLocation but its only response after enabling the GPS. if I am not enable GPS it provide Lat: 0.000000 Long: 0.000000

Can anyone suggest how to solve problem.

Comment: You can only use CoreLocation. The accuracy you request from CoreLocation will determine whether GPS is used or whether iOS tries to determine location from other sources such as wifi and cellular towers

Comment: if i need to use cellular then what accuracy i am used?? and if i am not enable the GPS then can it be work??

Comment: kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer doesn't activate the GPS, but what do you mean by "enable the GPS"?  To access the users location using any method, location services. Just be enabled and the user must give permission.